# cannot set property of undefined in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

```
export class ProductImage {
fileType: string;
fileContents: string;
};
```

When I try to use above class in Product component.

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

tileView = false;
isProductListEmpty = true;
token = localStorage.getItem('token');
productImage :ProductImage;




constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private productService : DesignerProductService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getDesignerProductList();
 
 this.productImage.fileType = "a";
 console.log(this.productImage.fileType);

 }
```

I get following error

product.component.html:50 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'fileType' of undefined

Seems like I am doing some silly mistake, I am new to angular ...what is wrong with declartion?

Comment: You have created productImage :ProductImage; but ever initialized it. Try adding this - `productImage  = new ProductImage()` in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Are you getting this error in your html file? If so, please paste the html file content where this property is accessed..

Comment: @singh_v lol... I thought syntax for initializing is different in typescript ..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You have declared type of 'productImage' here -`productImage :ProductImage;` but ever initialized it. Try adding this -
`productImage  = new ProductImage()` in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize that variable too

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private 
   productService : DesignerProductService) { 
    this.productImage= new ProductImage();
```

}

Hope it works..!!